# User metric issue in GA4 drives me crazy

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-4

I'm currently troubleshooting an issue with one of my GA4 properties. I hope someone can chime in and help me understand what is the reason for this?

When I set up a table to display the page path and the number of views for each path, I got a total of 8,199 distinct page paths with 306,645 views (table A).
[image]

However, the numbers change significantly when I include the 'total users' metric in the report. The view count decreases to 244,967, and the number of page paths plummets to just 727 (table B).

This means I'm missing over 90% of the page paths. Interestingly, when I focus solely on the user metric, it seems unaffected by the views metric, but the number of page paths still drops dramatically to 727 (Table C).

There are no sampling issues, I am using a page path standard GA4 dimension but it can be any other page-related dimension.

This behavior is not evident on my other accounts, page path dimension is showing the same number of distinct values when I add user metric.

Additionally, I am using a blended reporting identity with unavailable modeling yet. And there is the consent mechanism on the page

[image]

[image]